# Joint probability of the number of primes and the number of odds in five rolls of a fair die

Tags: probability

A balanced die is tossed $5$ times. Let $X$ be a random variable giving the number of rolls on which we observe a prime number. Let $Y$ be a random variable giving the number of rolls on which we observe an odd number. If $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ is the joint probability mass function for $X$ and $Y$ compute $f_{X,Y}(2,2)$

I think that in order to solve this I would have to look at the different types of outcomes such as prime and odd, prime and even etc.

Am I on the correct path in this thinking?
How could you show that these variables are independent?

Comment: You could show independence if $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_{X}(x)f_{Y}(y)$ for all $x,y$.  But it seems improbable, since there are more odd primes than even primes

Comment: how many sides does the die have?

Comment: die is standard 6 sides

Answer (score 1):

Let $U_i$ denote the number of rolls on which we observe number $i$, and let $W:=U_3+U_5$.

You are asked to find:$$f_{X,Y}(2,2)=\Pr(U_2+W=2=U_1+W)=\sum_{k=0}^2\Pr(U_2=2-k=U_1\mid W=k)\Pr(W=k)$$

$W$ has binomial distribution with parameters $n=5$ and $p=\frac26=\frac13$.

For the conditional probability we find:

$$\Pr(U_2=2-k=U_1\mid W=k)=\frac{(5-k)!}{(2-k)!(2-k)!(1+k)!}\left(\frac14\right)^{2-k}\left(\frac14\right)^{2-k}\left(\frac24\right)^{k+1}$$

Based on the trinomial distribution having parameters $5-k,\frac14,\frac14,\frac24$.